# How to get the ID from this URL?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to get the ID ( 153752044713801 in this case ) of this page:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9/153752044713801

I tried this code but doen't work:

```
var str = 0, pagefb = 0;
var fburl = 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9/153752044713801';

var re1 = /^(.+)facebook\.com\/pages\/([-\w\.]+)\/([-\w\.]+)/;

if(re1.exec(fburl)){
   str = re1.exec(fburl)[3]; 
   pagefb = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
   alert('ok');
}
```

Comment: split by '/' and catch last element from array ?

Comment: **Simple Enough?** `fburl.split('/').pop()`

Comment: already tried but doesn't work. pagefb is equal to "pages"

Comment: @xRobot I updated my answer, it should work in all your cases.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var fburl = 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9/153752044713801';
var parts = fburl.split("/");
var myId = parts[parts.length-1];
alert(myId);
```

Comment: what do you mean with that? I just tried that and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/zS7uQ8/1) regular expression: `^(.+)facebook\.com\/pages\/.*\/(\d*)`

(in JavaScript, you have to add "/" at the beginning and end of the pattern like you did before)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using `.split("/")`. More information is availible on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var fburl = 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9/153752044713801';

var parts = fburl.split('/')
var myFacebookId = parts[parts.length - 1]
```

Basically it returns an array of the string split into multiple parts (at the character/s you put inside the brackets).
The `parts[parts.length - 1]` will get the last item in the array `parts`

Demo below (Don't worry about the `document...`, they just print out data):

```js
var fburl = 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9/153752044713‌​801/?ref=sfhsidufh';

var parts = fburl.split('/')
var myFacebookId = parts[parts.length - 1]

// If first digit is ?
if (myFacebookId[0] == '?') {
    // Set myFacebookId to the second from last part
    myFacebookId = parts[parts.length - 2]
}

document.write('MyFacebookId: ' + myFacebookId)
```

Comment: it doesn't work in this case: facebook.com/pages/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9/153752044713801/?ref=sfhsidufh

Comment: How many more slashes could there be after the ID? If they are going to be like the case above, you can check if the first digit is a `?`, and if it is, select the previous part

Comment: @xRobot I updated the code in the answer, and added your link. Now it works in both cases. If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
fburl.split('/')[fburl.split('/').length-1]
```